# How to store the PHPersistentChangeToken?

Tags: swift, phphotolibrary

I just can't use NSUserDefault to store it:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(PHPhotoLibrary.shared().currentChangeToken, forKey: "token")
```

Here is the error:

```
[User Defaults] Attempt to set a non-property-list object <PHPersistentChangeToken: 0x600000e69f40: persistentHistoryToken=<NSPersistentHistoryToken - {
    "3F642A05-50EB-4DB3-8C26-3554B5F25849" = 110;
}>, version=1> as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key token
```

Comment: `PHPersistentChangeToken` conforms to `NS(Secure)Coding`, so you could use `NSKeyedArchiver`.